# Failed to execute 'table' on org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a Spark + Hive application.

It works fine. But at some point I had to create another Hive environment.

So I ran `show create table ...` and recreated the same view (with underlying tables). And added some data.

I can query the data from `hive cli`, etc.

but whenever I run my application it fails with

```
ERROR Failed to execute 'table' on 'org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession' with args=([Type=java.lang.String, Value: <view name>])
```

I believe it refers to the line code when I can `sparkSession.table(<view-name>)`

What steps can be executed to troubleshoot a such issue?

**UPD**

Session declaration (definitely tried to create a session without this configuration)

```
.Config("spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", "true")
.Config("spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", "some.file")
.Config("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
.Config("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", int64 2048)
.Config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", int64 2048)
```

Comment: can you try same by removing double quoted that you might have got while getting table definition from show create table.

Comment: thank you for the response. the original log does not contain quotes e.g. `args=([Type=java.lang.String, Value: my_table])`

Comment: Could you share the relevant bit of code where the error shows up?

Comment: Can you show your spark session declaration command. Did you use```.enableHiveSupport()``` option in your spark session

Comment: just updated the original post

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit trivial, but when it comes to troubleshooting this kind of an issue, *really* try and get to the root of the problem with a minimal set up:

- I generally start off by starting the `spark-shell`.
- Check whether it is possible to run `spark.sql("SHOW DATABASES").show(20, false)`. If this fails, it's probably something with your Hive configuration, indeed.
- Try and see whether you can run `spark.table("your_table")`. If not, it'll probably give you a clearer error (such as `Table or view not found: ...`).
- If all of the above works, try to strip your application such that it only does that `spark.table`, which *did* work in your `spark-shell` at that point in time. If that suddenly doesn't work, it might have to do with how the `SparkSession` is created in your application.
- If that works, try and uncomment the code piece by piece, until you're back to your original code to better pinpoint where it fails.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I can run `hive cli` from the same container, connect, query the data from the table/view with no issues. I'm running my job in GCP DataProc with no issues and it can query the data from a similar view. mostly the difference is that I'm using Google Store in DataProc, but local FS for my tests. And I copied Hive table with `show create table` which maybe does not contain all statements (don't think so)